# how to access PageViewController outside of widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview, flutter-bottomnavigation

TabScreen is my main widget in my app that includes a BottomNavigationBar and a PageView to transition between pages.

PageController allows me to change views and everything is fine here, but there is one thing missing. How can I change my PageView controller outside of TabScreen? I'd like to put a button to access my main PageView controller from within my pages.

```
class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  bool _isloading = true;
  int? _selectedIndex;
  List<Widget>? _pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    CurrenPlanDetail(),
    Container(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    SettingScreens(),
  ];
  PageController? _pageController;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedIndex = 0;

    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex!);
}

}

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              children: _pages!,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(
        visible: !_isloading,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: kNewPurple,
          //unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex!,
          onTap: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = value;
              _pageController!.jumpToPage(_selectedIndex!);
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Ionicons.home_outline,
                  size: 15.sp,
                ),
                label: 'Home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Ionicons.reader_outline,
                  size: 15.sp,
                ),
                label: 'Plan'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      fixedSize: Size(50, 50),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return FloatingButton();
                          });
                    },
                    child: Icon(Ionicons.add)),
                label: ''),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Ionicons.happy_outline,
                  size: 15.sp,
                ),
                label: 'Profile'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Ionicons.settings_outline,
                  size: 15.sp,
                ),
                label: 'Setting'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for example, somewhere in my app, I'd like to put a button and pass a function like this :

```
 _pageController!.jumpToPage(1);
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use Navigator to navigate to other pages

Comment: but my BottomNavigation ain't persist at all pages how can I Navigate to tabs from somewhere in my app

Answer (score 0):

Define PageController as static and

```
TabScreen.pageController.jumpToPage(1);
```

Comment: I've got this error through your  answer```ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
.```

Comment: Use static controller in PageView too